# Passing array with React using Ramda

Tags: reactjs, ramda.js

I would like to use which ever values are in "state" inside the  `Ramda` function. This would work similar to an "AND" filter. So it may receive 1 value, or several values.

How can I pass the data from the component into this ramda function?

How can it loop over the 'ramda' to add the values as they are set in state?

I added it to a codepen also: https://codesandbox.io/s/3OGK2pP9

```
const AndFilter = pipe(
  prop('movies'),
  filter(
    both(
   // Example data to show how it should arrive from the react component.
      where({ genres: pipe(pluck('name'), contains('foo')) }),
      where({ genres: pipe(pluck('name'), contains('bar')) }),
      where({ genres: pipe(pluck('name'), contains('baz')) }),
    ),
  ),
);

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      movies: dataTest,
      selectedFilters: { foo, bar, baz },
    };
  }
  AndFilter = () => {
    this.setState({ movies: AndFilter(x) });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.AndFilter}>test</button>
        {this.state.movies.map(movies => (
          <li key={movies.id}> {movies.name} </li>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably silly answer but why not just pass reference of your function to component props, like so:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.AndFilter=this.AndFilter.bind(this); 
    this.state = {
      movies: [{"name":"foo"}, {"name":"bar"},{"name":"baz"}],
      selectedFilters: {},
    };
  }

AndFilter(){
  this.setState({movies:this.props.AndFilter(this.state)});
}
____________________
let props={
   AndFilter:AndFilter,
   ....
}

<MyComponent {...props}>
```

**Edit:**

sorry i didn't look at your function i thought question about how pass it to component, you probably meant:

```
const AndFilter = pipe(
  prop('movies'),
  filter(
    allPass(
       [propEq('name','foo')]
    )
  ),
);
```

or like this (where comparators array of comparison functions):

```
const AndFilter = curry( 
   (comparators) => 
        pipe(
            prop('movies'),
            filter(
                allPass(
                 comparators
                )
            ),
       ) 
);
```

You can generate comparators in your component, i also forget to setup listener, look here https://codesandbox.io/s/pO8yWXM2, when you click on div it filters all guys except the ones who passes predicates.

Comment: Could you show me a more comprehensive example? Possibly on my pen? I tried implementing it without success. https://codesandbox.io/s/3OGK2pP9

Comment: I'm still not following. Your example is for differently structured data, and the `ramda` filters differently as well. Could you please do it here https://codesandbox.io/s/J6WW5BD9l? I do not see that the variables are being passed into the `AndFilter` const.